# How to run effect's cleanup of a component BEFORE rendering another one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-fast-bqoge?file=/src/App.js) as starter. If you click the Toggle button you'll see the following output in the console:

```
mount secondcomp 
unmount firstcomp
```

**How can I make it the other way arround?** So cleanup first component before rendering the second. **Is this possible at all?**

I do understand that effects are always run after render, but this is not what I want in my situation. In my use case I have a common resource (fetch-as-you-render pattern) whose methods are called **upon unmount of first** component and **on render of second**.

Comment: can u check this link I know it is not exactly what you want but a workaround? I am not sure if this solves your problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-shape-t6858?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox, but I'm looking for a solution with some kind of custom hook to do all the work and reuse it, so without adding additional props to components. Also I'd like to fetch data directly on render (not in an effect), that's what I meant by fetch-as-you-render.